# How to make my png disappear onCollision with another png?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, png, collision

Im making a game, where I'm moving the head of a windmill up and down the Y-axis with the ArrowUp and the ArrowDown keys.

I have wind going from left side of the screen to the right, on the x-axis only (using @keyframes).

**I need the wind to disappear when/if it hits the windmill-head, preferably using an if() statement.**

Both the wind and the windmill-head are png's with different divs and ids.

I am currently writing in html & js, styling it in css.

this is my current, non-functional if() statement:

```
function vindkollision()
{
    var vindforsvind = document.getElementsById("div1");
    var vindmøllehoved = document.getElementById("car");
    if(vindforsvind.x && vindforsvind.y == vindmøllehoved.x && vindmøllehoved.y)
    {
        vindforsvind.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Thank you!